# Unable to load dplyr with conda managed environment. magrittr reference broken

Tags: python, r, dplyr, conda

I am testing `conda` as a tool for package management for both `R` and `Python`. In particular, I am interested in testing the Microsoft R Client interpreter. I am experiencing issues in loading the `dplyr` package. I am working in Windows 7.

I setup the environment as follows:

```
conda create -n mrc --channel r r-mrclient-mml r-essentials
```

I activate the environment

```
activate mrc
```

I then load R.

```
R
```

Yet when I load `dplyr`, I get an exception.

```
library(dplyr)

#Error: package or namespace load failed for 'dplyr' in loadNamespace(j <- #i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
# there is no package called 'magrittr'
```

However, magrittr is installed. Because when I ran.

```
(mrc)$ conda list | grep 'magrittr'
r-magrittr                1.5                          0a    r
```

I have examined the **path** as well, and it shows conda activate is working as expected.

Any ideas on how I might solve this?

Comment: R searches for packages in the `R_LIBS_USER` environment variable. My first suggestion would be to run R as `R_LIBS_USER=/path/to/conda/R/library R`. Alternatively, you can set the library path from inside R with `.libPaths("/path/to/conda/R/library")`.

Comment: You can also call `.libPaths()` with no arguments to see where R is currently looking for installed packages. I generally find that to be useful when debugging issues like this.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyShiklomanov that helped a great deal! 

Something I observed now, is within the `conda/R/library` the magrittr subfolder wasn't there, despite conda referencing it as already installed when I try and install it manually via `conda install r-magrittr`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issues by running the installation of the packages in a step-by-step fashion.

`conda create -n mrc r
activate mrc
conda install r-mrclient-mml
conda install r-essentials`

It appears, conda may have a bug when it tries to solve the package dependencies through an approach of installing all the packages in a single command. i.e. `conda create -n mrc --channel r r-mrclient-mml r-essentials`.